# Jquery 2.1 - On click is stacking calls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a strange bug with on click event. Every time I click on button it is adding one more post call. If I click **update** button once it will do one **post** call, if I click it again (for the second time) it will make two **post** calls and so one. The code it self is working, but this bug is a bit annoying. Does anyone have idea what is going one?

```
var
    editCutomerType   = $('a[role=editCutomerType]'),
    deleteCutomerType = $('a[role=deleteCutomerType]');

editCutomerType.on('click', function(e) {
    var
        $this           = $(this),
        parentContainer = $this.closest('.parent'),
        nameContainer   = parentContainer.find('.name'),
        update          = $this.next('a'),
        cancel          = update.next('a'),
        oldName         = nameContainer.text()
        i = 0;

        $this.hide();
        update.removeClass('hidden');
        cancel.removeClass('hidden');

        nameContainer.empty().append('<input type=text name=name value="' + oldName + '">');

        update.on('click', function(e) {
            var
                url     = $(this).attr('href'),
                newName = parentContainer.find('input').val(),
                data    = 'name=' + newName;

                $.post(url, data, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    nameContainer.empty().text(newName);
                    $this.show();
                    update.addClass('hidden');
                    cancel.addClass('hidden');
                });
            return false;
        });

        cancel.on('click', function(e) {
            nameContainer.empty().text(oldName);
            $this.show();
            update.addClass('hidden');
            cancel.addClass('hidden');
            return false;
        });
        i++;
        console.log(i);
    return false;
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-7">
    <div class="panel panel-dark panel-light-green">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <span class="panel-title"><i class="panel-title-icon fa fa-smile-o"></i>Customer Types</span>
        </div> <!-- / .panel-heading -->
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody class="valign-middle">
                <?php
                    $i = 1;
                    foreach ($customerTypes as $ct): ?>
                    <tr class="parent">
                        <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
                        <td class="name"><?php echo $ct['name'] ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <a role="editCutomerType" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs hidden" href="<?php echo base_url("customerTypes/save/{$ct['id']}") ?>">Update</a>
                            <a role="cancel" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs hidden">Cancel</a>
                            <a role="deleteCutomerType" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="<?php echo base_url("customerTypes/delete/{$ct['id']}") ?>">Delete</a>
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php $i++; endforeach ?>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div> <!-- / .panel -->
</div>
```

Comment: You're binding a click handler inside another click handler. So every time you click on `editCustomerType`, you add another click handler to `update` and `cancel`.

Comment: @Barmar Exactly my thougts, should be an answer.

Comment: You should just bind those other click handlers once. But we need to see the HTML to know the correct selectors for them.

Comment: I see. How can I bind it only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your update link a role like your other buttons:

```
                foreach ($customerTypes as $ct): ?>
                <tr class="parent">
                    <td><?php echo $i ?></td>
                    <td class="name"><?php echo $ct['name'] ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <a role="editCutomerType" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Edit</a>
                        <a role="update" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs hidden" href="<?php echo base_url("customerTypes/save/{$ct['id']}") ?>">Update</a>
                        <a role="cancel" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs hidden">Cancel</a>
                        <a role="deleteCutomerType" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="<?php echo base_url("customerTypes/delete/{$ct['id']}") ?>">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            <?php $i++; endforeach ?>
```

Then you can bind handlers for `update` and `cancel` outside the `editCutomerType` handler:

```
$("a[role=update]").on('click', function(e) {
        var
            $this = $(this),
            cancel = $this.next('a'),
            edit = $this.prev('a'),
            url     = $this.attr('href'),
            newName = $this.closest('.parent').find('input').val(),
            nameContainer = parentContainer.find('.name'),
            data    = 'name=' + newName;

            $.post(url, data, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                nameContainer.empty().text(newName);
                edit.show();
                $this.addClass('hidden');
                cancel.addClass('hidden');
            });
        return false;
    });
```

You can do the `cancel` button similarly.

Answer (score 1):

To stop the handler from being executed more than once, add [stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/) to the function.

```
    update.on('click', function(e) {
        var
            url     = $(this).attr('href'),
            newName = parentContainer.find('input').val(),
            data    = 'name=' + newName;

            $.post(url, data, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                nameContainer.empty().text(newName);
                $this.show();
                update.addClass('hidden');
                cancel.addClass('hidden');
            });
        return false;
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the old handler, you can call update.off('click').on('click', ...

Do the same for the cancel event.

Sent from phone, so sorry for not being verbose.